# How to see all custom formatting rules in a sheet, not just those applying to current selected cells?

Tags: google-sheets

As far as I can tell, in Google Sheets you only see a list of formatting rules applying to your current selection.
Is there a way to see a list of all rules that exist in a sheet? When people copy-paste between cells they often mangle these rules and this would make fixing it easier.

Answer (score 3):

Select All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and go to *Format* → *Conditional Formation*.

This will show you every active conditional formatting rule even if some cells are hidden.